# RESTEasy + Asynchronous + Callback Method + Java

Tags: java, asynchronous, callback, resteasy

I want to support both Synchronous and Asynchronous call using RESTEasy-JAXRS. And my asynchronous call should be based on callback, where Async request will have callbackURI, request gets processed asynchronously and upon completion makes a call to callbackURI with operation status/result. Can someone point me out to correct place? I see lot about polling model, but not callback with RESTEasy.

I am new to Asynchronous stuff...

Thanks in advance!

Thanks for your response rmlan.Yes but we have support in JAX-RS to handle asynchronous using @Suspended & AsyncResponse. I did that with following code, but i am unable to find the way to make callback to Client who called the API upon completion of task with this request.

```
@GET
@Path("/async")
public String checkAsync(@Suspended final AsyncResponse response) {
    response.setTimeoutHandler(new TimeoutHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleTimeout(AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
            response.resume(Response.status(Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
                    .entity("Operation time out.").build());
        }
    });
    response.setTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String result = veryExpensiveOperation();
                response.resume(result);
            }

            private String veryExpensiveOperation() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                logger.debug("Task is processed fully");
                return "Successful";
            }
        }).start();

    return "nothing";
}
```

Comment: How the client handles the call and response to your RESTEasy service really has nothing to do with RESTEasy. Whether or not to perform an asynchronous call would be entirely up to the client.

Comment: Thanks for your response rmlan!. I have added my code above. Can you please drop me some idea?

Answer (score -1):

Every method in class has one return ( or maybe void ) . but sometimes you need some callbacks from your method . this is the solution .

```
public abstract class MyClass {

    public abstract void myCallbackMethod();

    public void myMethod(){

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            // do somthing
            myCallbackMethod();// it will implements in future.
        }

    }
}
```

when you make an object from ***MyClass*** , you must implement  ***myCallbackMethod*** abstract method . like this

```
public class NewMain {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
       MyClass myClass=new MyClass() {

           @Override
           public void myCallbackMethod() {
               System.err.println("this is call back");
           }
       };
       myClass.myMethod();
    }
    
}
```

and the result is

> this is call back
>
> this is call back
>
> this is call back
>
> this is call back
>
> this is call back

it means you can get five call backs from void method in your class.
it is a good way when you do not have any idea for the body content of ***myCallBackMethod***

the real example is download a file from server in your app .

you can call ***myCallBackMethod*** when bytes received and progress your progressbar